# Ruined styles when adding empty explpreset

Tags: highlighting, showexpl

I'm trying to show LaTeX commands using package showexpl. In the documentation of the package, it says that `explpreset` has a default value of  . I think the sentence in documentation is not completed since it missed a full stop mark.

But when I add `explpreset={}` in defining style, it somehow ruins the style, what I first see the problem, is that the `begin` is not highlighted (`end` and most others are highlighted, though).

I'm curious how adding `explpreset={}` makes that difference. Does `explpreset` actually contain something in the beginning, or did I used it in a wrong way?

Also, what is special about the keyword `begin` that makes it not properly highllighted?

Here's MWE and the result:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\lstdefinestyle{codestyle1}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    pos=b
}
\lstdefinestyle{codestyle2}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    pos=b,
    explpreset = {}
}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=TeX,style=codestyle1}
\begin{LTXexample}
    \begin{center}
        Some text with code style1
    \end{center}
\end{LTXexample}

\begin{LTXexample}[explpreset={}]
    \begin{center}
        Some text with code style1 with empty explpreset
    \end{center}
\end{LTXexample}

\lstset{language=TeX,style=codestyle2}
\begin{LTXexample}
    \begin{center}
        Some text with code style2 with empty explpreset
    \end{center}
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

[image: different styles when empty explpreset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default settings for `explpreset` can be found in the source code of `showexpl`, near the end of the file `showexpl.sty`:

```
\lstset{explpreset={numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,numbersep=.3em,
  xleftmargin=1em,columns=flexible,language=[LaTeX]TEX},pos=l,width=-99pt,
  overhang=0pt,hsep=\columnsep,vsep=\bigskipamount,rframe=single}
```

This explains the differences in the third block of your output: no line numbers and wider text (because of `columns=flexible`). The difference in highlighting is probably caused by the language setting `TeX` instead of `[LaTeX]TeX`, because `begin` is a LaTeX-specific keyword and the default dialect for the TeX language setting in listings is `plain` and not `LaTeX`. The `end` keyword on the other hand is part of the `primitive` set which is loaded by `TeX`.

It does not explain why the empty preset is ignored in the second example though. This may be a bug in processing the environment options - but I'm not entirely sure that this is the case.